# In Smalltalk, how do you print specific elements of an array?

Tags: arrays, smalltalk

I am working on an introductory smalltalk program. The goal is to print all elements of an array of integers forward, backward, and then print only the elements of the array that end in a certain digit.

I have already done the first two, but I'm stuck on how I should handle the last goal.

Here is my code:

```
|myArray|
myArray _ Array new: 15.
1 to: 15 do: [:i | myArray at:i put:i*2].
myArray printNl.
myArray reverse printNl.
```

Comment: What exactly are you stuck with? Extracting the last digit of an integer or printing only some of the elements of an array, instead of all of them?

Comment: My issue is extracting the last digit.

Answer (score 2):

Is this for a class or are you following a tutorial? What other concepts have your learned (either in this class or in other languages)? If you couldn't send the #'printNl' message, what would you do?

I think that the purpose of this exercise is to introduce you to using loops (to iterate forwards and backwards), and to conditionals inside a loop (have you been introduced to conditionals and branching yet?).

If you had a loop that printed each element of the array, you could add a conditional (such as an #'ifTrue:' message) to isolate the printing.

Comment: I'm a 3rd year student and this is for a class about various programming languages. The assignment vaguely follows a tutorial We've talked about the language for one lecture period so far.

I've already familiarized myself with the looping structure of the language, but where languages that I'm used to have a getCharAt() function or similar, Smalltalk appears to have no such method at my disposal. So my issue isn't the idea of a conditional so much as there isn't a method that I've seen in the language notes that does what I need.

Comment: Smalltalk's equivalent is #'at:'.

Answer (score 0):

It depends a bit on the dialect you are using.

I think the important thing is to realize that an Integer is not a String and therefore, they have different behaviour.

```
|myArray tail|
myArray := Array new: 15.
tail := '6'.
1 to: 15 do: [:i | myArray at:i put:i*2].
myArray do:[:entry | (entry asString matchesTail:tail) ifTrue:[entry "whatever your need to do with it"] ].
```